# Creating custom angular directive for term.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, terminal

I am creating a custom directive for my own use, specifically [term.js](https://github.com/chjj/term.js/). It is normally very simple to use:

```
var term = new Terminal({
   cols: 80,
   rows: 24,
   screenKeys: true
});

term.open(document.body);
term.write('\x1b[31mWelcome to term.js!\x1b[m\r\n');
```

To do so, I modified a hello-world directive example to suit my needs:

```
app.directive('terminal', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            name: '@'
        },
        template: '<span>Hello {{name}}<div class="term"></div></span>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var term = new Terminal({
                cols: 80,
                rows: 24,
                screenKeys: true
            });
            // window.w = elem;
            term.open(elem.find("div"));
            term.write('\x1b[31mWelcome to term.js!\x1b[m\r\n');
        }
    }
});
```

And I use it in my HTML as:

```
<terminal name="Terminal 1"></terminal>
```

However, although I see "Hello Terminal 1" on web page, the folllowing error is shown in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined
    at Terminal.open (http://localhost:4000/js/term.js:700:43)
    at link (http://localhost:4000/js/MyApp.js:23:18)
```

I am fairly new to AngularJS, cannot figure out what is wrong. elem.find() seems to return a DOM object, there is no .get() method like in JQuery, but it does not matter I have tried it with JQquery too, (instead of jqLite). So what is the problem I cannot see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I needed to do:

```
     term.open(elem.find("div")[0]);
```